# Java to Smali instruction converter

Tags: java, android, openurl, smali

I need to convert this instruction in smali code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I want modify an application and I want add this function to open android browser to point a specific webpage (for example www.google.com).

I try to use 'dx' plugin in Android Studio but I don't have any result...
Thank you!

Comment: "but I don't have any result" is not a very good description of what happened, unless you ran it and it literally did nothing. Did you get an error? Was the output not what you expected?

Answer (score 2):

You generally can't just copy and paste bytecode/smali code from one method
to another. At a minimum, you'll need to fix up the registers. And it can get more complicated if you need to allocate more registers, etc.

Compiling java code to smali is a good way to learn, but don't expect to be able to copy and paste the bytecode as-is.

As you already mentioned, you can to use dx to convert a java class file to a dex file.

```
javac Blah.java
dx --dex --output=classes.dex Blah.class
```

And then, of course, you can run baksmali on the classes.dex to disassemble it to smali code.

```
baksmali classes.dex
```

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for this in future, here is the basic gist of it. You'll have to make sure to fix the registers. Assuming v2 to be URL string:

```
    invoke-static {v2}, Landroid/net/Uri;->parse(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/net/Uri;
    
    move-result-object v2

    new-instance v4, Landroid/content/Intent;

    const-string v5, "android.intent.action.VIEW"

    invoke-direct {v4, v5, v2}, Landroid/content/Intent;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/net/Uri;)V

    invoke-virtual {p0,v4}, Landroid/app/Activity;->startActivity(Landroid/content/Intent;)V
```